# Decode URL after redirect link

Tags: java, android, android-intent, browser, decode

I have a url1 that not be encoded

```
String url1="http://bitake.com/params/?attribute=3"
```

And here url2( url after redirect of url1) be encoded

```
String url2="http://search.bitake.com/params/?attr=48%e6%99%82%e9%96%93%e3%82"
```

I use this link to open browswer with Intent

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW",   
                                      Uri.parse(URLDecoder.decode(url));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

I want to get url2 from url1 by code..Then decode url2 to can open in web
How must I do?

Answer (score 0):

i think your url1 is not a valid url. Can not decode to a valid url neither by utf8 nor GB

Answer (score 0):

You URL1 is not a valid URL. URLDecoder.decode(string url) is deprecated. You should use URLDecode.decode(String url, String enc) where enc is the character encoding.

Also `%` must be encoded as `%25`

```
public class DecodeTest
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {

      String url="http://bitake.com/params/?attribute=3";

      String url1="http://search.bitake.com/params/?attr=48%25e6%2599%2582%25e9%2596%2593%25e3%2582%25";

      try
      {
         System.out.println(URLDecoder.decode(url,"UTF-8"));
         System.out.println(URLDecoder.decode(url1, "UTF-8"));
      }
      catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
      {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Here I only want to get url1 (url after redirect) to decode url1.

Comment: I'm sorry, I do not understand what you are asking.

Comment: Try using the url1 in the code I provided in my solution. See if that resolves your problem. My url1 is different from yours.